# Take a JSON Object Value and put it into a Javascript variable

Tags: javascript, json

I know how to put the whole JSON into Javascript, but I don't know how to take 1 object value and put it into a javascript variable.

For example if I wanted the value of "start_time" below, in a variable in Javascript.

```
{
    "result": {
        "status": 1,
        "num_results": 10,
        "total_results": 500,
        "results_remaining": 490,
        "matches": [
            {
                "match_id": 515853415,
                "match_seq_num": 469991846,
                "start_time": 1392156202,
                "lobby_type": 7,
                "players": [
....
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var JS = JSON.parse(yourJSONString);
var start_time = JS.results.matches[0].start_time;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get the json from the back-end via an XHR request then you need to parse it first and  convert it into a JavaScript object

```
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
```

Then you can access the start_time property as you would access any other property of a JavaScript object

```
obj.result.matches[0]['start_time']
```